# Cannot edit data in MS Access form, it says "Recordset is not updatable"

Tags: forms, ms-access, ms-access-2010

I have a form, that holds a subform which displays data from a simple query based on the content in a input field.

I have set the properties of both forms to the following, but I still experience the "Recordset is not updatable" message.

Recordset type: Dynaset


Allow Additions: Yes

Allow Deletions: Yes

Allow Edits: Yes

Allow Filters: Yes

Record Locks: No Locks

What to change?

Comment: Open your queries and see if they are updatable.

Comment: What's the name of that property?

Comment: I'm using a select query, and on top of that I have this vba code for my inputfield, in order to make a live search: Me.f_q_test.Form.RecordSource = _
"select * from q_test WHERE q_test.Navn like ('*" & Me.Text0.Text & "*');"

Comment: I don't know that `.Text` does what you think.  Try `Me.Text0` instead.  Is `Text0` bound to an field in q_test?  Navn, perhaps?

Comment: As @coge.soft says, .text has specific uses in MS Access and is only available when the control has focus. The .value property is the default, so Me.text0 will return .value q_Test sounds like a query. If you are querying a query, make sure the fisrt query is updateable.

Comment: Yes it is. 'Navn' is the name field of the query.

Comment: Is q_Test a query and is it updatable?

Comment: Yes it's a query that just selects all field from a table, without any filter. It has No locks. I cant see any property of the query called Updatable?

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps one of the tables or queries that your query links to do not have Primary Keys.

OR (and this was the problem I had)
In the Query Builder, make sure the `Group By` row is not enabled.  When you disable this then the query will become editable.

Group By Enabled

[image: Group By enabled]

Right-click on the row and disbable `Totals`

[image: Right-Click row]

Group By disabled

[image: Group By disabled]

[This page has some good info for troubleshooting](http://www.fmsinc.com/MicrosoftAccess/query/non-updateable/index.html).

Answer (score 0):

Make Text0 unbound (remove Navn as the Control source).  You have what amounts to a circular reference.

You're telling the form not to show any data except what is limited by the query, but you're having the query not show any data except what is in your form.

Comment: It seems like this is not the root problem. I have another version where it works with: select * from q_test WHERE q_test.AccountName like ('*" & Me.Text0.Text & "*');" It must be some kind of write setting that is missing?

Comment: look at the control source for Text0 on both forms (the working and non-working).  Does the working one say, `Unbound`?

Answer (score 0):

I ran into this issue and it was due to relationships between the tables. I had a few set as Indeterminate and believe this was causing the issue. Once I modified my table relationships so that all were One-to-Many, I was able to edit fields in the query/form.

-Note that to have a one-to-many relationship, one field in the relationship must be a key or set to Unique.

Answer (score 0):

I encountered this error with a Access 2016 form created with the form wizard.
It set some variables like Data Entry to No.
But what locked the form from edits was the filter and sort.
I had to tell both the filter and sort 'No'
When I reopened the form nothing was showing.
I filtered on something then cleared filters.
Now the form is working.

Answer (score 0):

In my case I made a table where I joined the possible combination mixes from various other tables with a number of corresponding many-to-one relations. In the subsequent query using just this one combination table it became unupdateable if I checked the "Unique Values" in the query's property sheet. It works ok checking the "Unique Records".

The downside is that when filtering on one of the combination fields in the query I now get all those lines (records) from the combination table where this particular field has got the filter value. I wouldn't get that if I checked the "Unique Values".

I guess the solution is to make two separate queries: one unupdateable for just querying and then a copy query (except for unchecking "Unique Values" when updating is required).

At least you get your relationships right.

Answer (score 0):

corrupted tables can sometimes lose their primary keys and that could be the cause of "Recordset is not updatable" message.

Answer (score 0):

I found the same issue with a recordset not updatable but it seemed intermittent.  The subform recordset was updatable, then it was not.  When it was not updatable, I had to go back to an early copy of the database.  In the earlier copy, the recordset was updatable.  What I found was that if I sorted the subform data and closed the form, access saved the "Order by" clause in the subform properties - I never ran any command to save the subform.  With this "Order by" set, the subform recordset was not updatable.  The Fix:  I added an initialize routine to all subforms to remove the order by, before the main form is opened.  Wala!  Recordset of subform is now updatable every time.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

I was getting the same issue. I have to add the primary key field in the table at my end and it started working.

So right-click on the table and add the primary key or make the existing unique column as the primary key.

Go to your MSACCESS -> Right click on app and Refresh Link

[image]

[image: ![enter image description here]

Answer (score -1):

Above `Allow Additions: Yes` you should have something like
`Allow datainput`. Make sure this field is set to `false`. If you read the status bar comment when you have this field selected you will understand why your table suddenly became unediteable from your formular :)